# Pass a value to a class via a constructor or a method?

Tags: design, java, clean-code

I'm newbie in Java and I have question. Pass a value to a class via a constructor or a method?

```
public class HelloWorld{
     public static void main(String []args){
        TextModifyFirstVersion textmodifyFirstVersion = new TextModifyFirstVersion("test");
        textmodifyFirstVersion.modify();
        
        TextModifySecondVersion textmodifySecondVersion = new TextModifySecondVersion();
        textmodifySecondVersion.modify("test");
     }
}

class TextModifyFirstVersion {
  String text;
  
  public TextModifyFirstVersion(String text) {
    text = text;
  }

  public void modify() {
    String test = privateMethod();
    //some operations on text
  }

  String privateMethod() {
    //some operations on text
    return text;
  }
}


class TextModifySecondVersion {
  public void modify(String text) {
    String test = privateMethod(text);
    //some operations on text
  }

  String privateMethod(String text) {
    //some operations on text
    return text;
  }
}
```

Which version is better and why? TextModifyFirstVersion or TextModifySecondVersion? Both versions work well, but which is better and will be better in the future for this type of class?

Comment: Neither is better - simply use whichever best fits your needs

Comment: If the using code looks like `result = new TextModify(text).modify();` then it doesn't mater. If the using code looks like `result = modifer.modify();` then you have decoupled setting the text from calling for it's modification. If doing that maters to you then yes, it maters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects represent abstractions — the binding together of various values into a single entity.  This binding is accomplished by constructor parameters.

Given decent abstraction, the consuming callers need create and think about fewer objects.  It relieves consumers of some cognitive burdens, when things work simply for them.

One reason to create classes in the first place is to bind multiple values (of lower abstraction) together so the consumer has to deal with only one entity.  (Of course, we can go to far with this and if we do the consumer might have to resort to decomposing into piece parts.)

When values are constant for the lifetime of the object, they should be supplied on construction.

When values are constant only for the lifetime of some method, they should be supplied at method invocation.

For in between situations, such as a value that will remain constant across a number of methods, but not the whole lifetime of the object, this indicates there is potentially a missing abstraction (i.e. missing class) that should hold the values and bindings of more intermediate duration.

So, I would look to the usage scenarios and take it from there.  What makes the consuming caller's life simpler?  So they can deal with object creation and object usage in the simplest or most natural way for them.

Comment: So TextModifyFirstVersion or TextModifySecondVersion? :)

Comment: Yeah, good one ;)